# How to pass bunch of lists through by linq?

Tags: c#

I am new to `Linq`, I had collection of lists, what I want is I need to pass that lists through by `Linq` query and I need to return based on list items exists in DB

The function was like this..

```
 public IList<ApprovalChainList> GetAllApprovalChain(string rqtype, List<decimal> rectype, List<decimal> Requestor, decimal? LocationIDUL, List<decimal> CostCenter, decimal? LocationIDCC, int pageIndex, int PageSize)
        {
 List<ApprovalChainList> APLIst = new List<ApprovalChainList>();
{try{

}

return APLIst ;




}
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide more details and clarify your question?

Comment: I can guarantee you that the function was not like that. That code would never compile in C#.

Comment: In my case i am creating dynamic check boxes through jquery and i need to pass that chechbox values to action method through json post method,the issue is if values i declared as decimal,it will not pass through json post method,i have to declared as string list and i am passing to action method,but in entities that field was declared as decimal..i am creating dynamic check box in jquery as like this

Answer (score 0):

For specific answer to your question needs more clarification but i will show you how to execute where condition and select particular records from LINQ query. May it solve your purpose.

```
APLIst = (from m in APLIst
         where m.rectype.Contains(rectype)).ToList()
         .Skip(pageIndex* PageSize)
         .Take(PageSize);
```

Comment: Yes it was solved,but I had one more issue,that input rectype i am passing from json post method as string list,but in m.rectype it was in decimal..Is there any function  to convert string list to decimal list???

Comment: `myList.ForEach(x => x = x.Convert.ToDecimal(x))`

Comment: To convert string list to decimal list use :  `myList.Select(x => decimal.Parse(x)).ToList();`

Comment: The code as like this:public ActionResult ApprovalChainSearchList(Approvalchain itm)
        { 
            
            ApprovalChainViewModel resultView = null;


        try
        {
            List<decimal> kl = itm.REQUESTOR.Select(x => decimal.Parse(x)).ToList();  It was throwing error input string was not correct format..

Comment: If your input string list contains any item which is not decimal it throws error input string was not correct format.

Comment: In my case i am creating dynamic check boxes through jquery and i need to pass that chechbox values to action method through json post method,the issue is if values i declared as decimal,it will not pass through json post method,i have to declared as string list and i am passing to action method,bot in entities that field was declared as decimal..i am creating dynamic check box in jquery as like this:::